# Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: status

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When i run my app it crashes and says it gets two getters of status. But in my code i have written Status not status. I don't know what is wrong please help me!
This is  `Contacts.java`

```
public class Contacts
{
    public String name, Status, image;

    public Contacts()
    {

    }

    public Contacts(String name, String Status, String image)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.Status = Status;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return Status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
       this. Status = status;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

Here is `FindFreindsActivity.java`

```
public class FindFreindsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private RecyclerView FindfreindsRecyclerList;

    private DatabaseReference UsersRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_freinds);

        UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

        FindfreindsRecyclerList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.find_freinds_recycler_list);
        FindfreindsRecyclerList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.find_freinds_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Find Freinds");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Contacts> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Contacts>()
                .setQuery(UsersRef, Contacts.class)
                .build();

        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Contacts,FindFreindsViewHolder >adapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Contacts, FindFreindsViewHolder>(options) {
                    @Override
                    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FindFreindsViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull Contacts model) {

                        holder.userName.setText(model.getName());
                        holder.userStatus.setText(model.getStatus());
                        Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.profile_image).into(holder.profileImage);


                    }

                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public FindFreindsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)
                    {
                        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.users_display_layout, viewGroup, false);
                        FindFreindsViewHolder viewHolder = new FindFreindsViewHolder(view);
                        return viewHolder;
                    }
                };

        FindfreindsRecyclerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.startListening();

    }

    public static class FindFreindsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView userName, userStatus;
        CircleImageView profileImage;

        public FindFreindsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            userName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_profile_name);
            userStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_status);
            profileImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.users_profile_image);

        }

    }
}
```

In my firebase database status is written as Status and this activity is supposed to show all the people using this app, with their profile pic , username and their status.

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Contacts object provides two ways to get a property called "status".

The first one is the fact that you've made `Status` a **public** member:

```
public String name, Status, image;
```

The second is your accessor method:

```
public String getStatus() {
    return Status;
}
```

The standard way to write POJO objects is to make your fields **private** and provide only public accessor methods.

Do this instead:

```
private String name, Status, image;
```

Also consider making `status` lowercase, as is the standard for Java object fields.

Comment: Actually: either of those changes will fix the problem, as with `public String name, status, image;` the casing conflict disappears too.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson Thankyou so much your answer worked for me!